# I want to add a green box below the yellow one

Tags: flutter

I wanted to add a green box below the yellow box. So please help me add that below. I got it mostly done. But don't know how to proceed with the rest. I am new to this and don't know what to do. I am just learning to code in Dart.

````
  runApp(
    Myapp()
  );

}

class Myapp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        body: SafeArea(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
          height: double.infinity,
          width: 100.0,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 100.0,
          color: Colors.yellow,
        ),
          Container(
          height: double.infinity,
          width: 100.0,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
          ],
        ),
        ),
      ), 
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,     
    );
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this App Brewery's challenge, isn't it? 
Here's a hint, to add a green box below yellow, wrap the yellow box container with column widget and add it to the recently created column widget.

Comment: what is App Brewery's challenge?

Comment: I think it is a challenge in a course by Angela on udemy: Here is the link: https://www.udemy.com/course/flutter-bootcamp-with-dart/

Comment: App Brewery, founded by Angela Yu(renowned educator), in her flutter course, has assigned a challenge to replicate a layout using the knowledge that she has taught.
Also, she is providing first few hours of her course for free:
https://www.appbrewery.co/p/intro-to-flutter?utm_source=google&utm_medium=website%20banner&utm_campaign=app_brewery

Answer (score 1):

To add a green box under the yellow box, wrap your yellow box with a `Column` widget and put your yellow box below it.

Check the code below:
It works perfectly:

```
MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        body: SafeArea(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
          height: double.infinity,
          width: 100.0,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
            // your column widget here
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            // your yellow box here
            Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 100.0,
              color: Colors.yellow,
            ),
            // your green box here
             Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 100.0,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
          ],
        ),
          Container(
          height: double.infinity,
          width: 100.0,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
          ],
        ),
        ),
      ), 
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,     
    );
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Myapp());
}

class Myapp extends StatelessWidget {
  // const ({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        body: SafeArea(
          child:Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[

              Container(
                height: double.infinity,
                width: 100.0,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  // your yellow box here
                  Container(
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100.0,
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                  ),
                  // your green box here
                  Container(
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100.0,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                height: double.infinity,
                width: 100.0,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ],

          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).